# Optimally allocating resources?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I have been searching for a solution to my below problem but without luck. I am wondering if there could be a solution that is perhaps a branch of [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) but I haven't been able to find anything - so my first question should really be:

*"Is there an approach to maximizing the number of series' (eg class schedules) that can fit into a finite number of resources (eg classrooms)?*

## My problem:

Assuming/hoping it is possible, here is an example scenario with the following assumptions:
 - Classrooms are available from 9am until 4pm, Monday to Friday
 - All classes are 1 hour in length
 - Classrooms for a specific lesson type have to occur in one of the corresponding rooms

I have 10 classrooms:

- 4 general-purpose (for registration, history, languages, technology - and of course Maths!
- 2 Science
- 2 Art
- 1 Music
- 1 Library

I have a ranked list of schedules I need to fit (as many as possible) in - and each class should begin a day with a registration class and then the other classes can be in any order:

1. Class01: 2 days/week of 4 hours: Maths/science/technology
2. Class02: 4 days/week of 3 hours: Art/Music/Library
3. Class03: 1 day/week  of 6 hours: Art/Music/Library
4. Class04: 4 days/week of 3 hours: Art/Music/Library
5. ...etc...

Comment: Are you familiar with matchings in graphs or the max flow/ min cut algorithm? If you relax the days/week condtion then your problem is easily solvable by such methods.

Comment: Thanks @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης, I did not know of that! I have been reading through and would appreciate any guidance as it as I'm finding it difficult to digest. Am I on the right track thinking I need "Project selection problem" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem ?